# How create custom function afterRender for existing template in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, magento2

I want to call a custom JS function after the checkout address form is loaded by knockoutjs.
How can I do that?

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include the code you have currently written? At the moment your question is too broad for us to be able to help you. Try sharing the current state of your code and anything that you've tried so far.

Comment: As Tim said, you'll have to provide a bit more information for us to be able to help you.
What is the checkout address form, loaded as component?